# Can we dupe this question about Pathfinder half-humans the other way?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, duplicates

The question in question is [To what extent are half-breeds treated as humans?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116345/14848)

I agree with KRyan that the older question(s), while duplicate, is/are not written or supported nearly as well as the new one.  I know that sometimes when that happens we dupe the other way with answer migration.  Is this a good use-case for that?  Can we do that?

Specifically, can we move things around to close [Do the Elf Blood racial trait allow you to fulfil "being an elf" prerequisites?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104286/do-the-elf-blood-racial-trait-allow-you-to-fulfil-being-an-elf-prerequisites) and [Can a half-elf take human traits?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102003/can-a-half-elf-take-human-traits) as duplicates of [To what extent are half-breeds treated as humans?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116345/14848)

Answer (score 5):

I'm reopening it with no further closures yet.

We can't close as dupe of a question with no answers, and this question doesn't appear to be the same as the others so it looks reasonable to reopen it and do nothing further.

If it's going to be a good canonical question on this subject worth pointing to as a dupe target, I'd like to see it gather answers that show we should do that with it.  Consider this reopen a chance for it to prove itself before we re-assess what ought to be closed as a duplicate of what (if anything).

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence, especially since I was somewhat rushed while writing that question. I'll be adding more general information to it that I remembered after the fact.